# Trying to understand Solana Markets and Data Models

Tags: python, raydium

I'm working on trying to replicate the payload returned by Raydium from their liquidity pool data, but using python.

```
{
  "id": "EP2ib6dYdEeqD8MfE2ezHCxX3kP3K2eLKkirfPm5eyMx",
  "baseMint": "EKpQGSJtjMFqKZ9KQanSqYXRcF8fBopzLHYxdM65zcjm",
  "quoteMint": "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112",
  "lpMint": "CQurpF3WS3yEqFEt1Bu8s5zmZqznQG3EJkcYvsyg3sLc",
  "baseDecimals": "6",
  "quoteDecimals": "9",
  "lpDecimals": "6",
  "version": "4",
  "programId": "675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8",
  "authority": "5Q544fKrFoe6tsEbD7S8EmxGTJYAKtTVhAW5Q5pge4j1",
  "openOrders": "6jeayPbLeJq9o6zXbCtLsEJuPyPFyojWoH55xrksfsoL",
  "targetOrders": "2yBDs44FDGZeXbnx1MdmAMYx9ndFFVWTbcrjJB1JMLSR",
  "baseVault": "7UYZ4vX13mmGiopayLZAduo8aie77yZ3o8FMzTeAX8uJ",
  "quoteVault": "7e9ExBAvDvuJP3GE6eKL5aSMi4RfXv3LkQaiNZBPmffR",
  "withdrawQueue": "11111111111111111111111111111111",
  "lpVault": "11111111111111111111111111111111",
  "marketVersion": "4",
  "marketProgramId": "srmqPvymJeFKQ4zGQed1GFppgkRHL9kaELCbyksJtPX",
  "marketId": "EzMCG3oJpXu2enNAh2A18iSg6Giq3Bt1wPDFDDiYgxeY",
  "marketAuthority": "Bo9ofFBTrT7GjrjZCseQuB7Hd91d9Ya5G3srhUEDBLD2",
  "marketBaseVault": "58LQCd9EXd4npbyaPAYztwKr54fHyXkGGUB6zt4GXTLA",
  "marketQuoteVault": "H9uqrbTrpZCVRv2sZah2kf6NfNdV7ZhUJrku1TCfnrsT",
  "marketBids": "34bsaKr4CH6YPNJQqXnxp1BGygvqBYKz4RTndbFFrVYe",
  "marketAsks": "C2DK9zXcy2XaMUFDCgtCEkovrYpf1dxB4P1JFEakp9gf",
  "marketEventQueue": "6gpR7brnKCPqPwSRCU2PRGGNLEsoqsjudYfMNub5DEYd",
  "lookupTableAccount": "A9F1oBqaAFFJqjmevgeWEDQdhahgkNupsowrWjc5Fwp9"
}
```

I have been able to figure out all of the properties except `marketAuthority`. My guess is that I have to use the `find_program_address` function of solders.Pubkey but I cannot for the life of me figure out which parameters to pass in.

Does anyone have any experience with this specific scenario for raydium and python?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `create_program_address` with `seed`.

Try converting this function type script to python

https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-sdk/blob/master/src/serum/serum.ts#L41